# Permissions mode for child apps in current 3.x facebook-phpsdk

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

I have been reading the facebook dev documentation as well as previous iterations of the php sdk. the old sdks had a 'permissions' mode for child apps [begin_permissions_mode(), end_permissions_mode()], but i see no references for a similar mode in the current 3.x php sdk. Does this functionality still exist?